# how do I write good marble tests for NGRX effects with service calls?

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngrx

I have the following effect:

```
createListConfirm$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(listActions.createListConfirm),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(projectSelectors.getCurrentProjectId)),
      switchMap(([action, projectId]) => this.listService.createList(action.payload, projectId)),
      switchMap(result => of(listActions.createListSuccess({ payload: result }))),
      catchError(() => of(listActions.createListFailed())),
    ),
  );
```

and have written the following unit tests:

```
  describe('createListConfirm$', () => {
    it('dispatches createListSuccess', () => {
      action = hot('a', { a: listActions.createListConfirm({ payload: createListReq }) });
      const response = cold('a|', { a: payload })
      const expected = cold('-b|', { b: listActions.createListSuccess({ payload }) });
      expect(effects.createListConfirm$).toBeObservable(expected);
    })
    it('dispatches createListFailed', () => {
      action = hot('a', { a: listActions.createListConfirm({ payload: createListReq }) });
      const error = cold('#');
      listService.createList.mockReturnValue(throwError(error));
      const expected = cold('(b|', { b: listActions.createListFailed() });
      expect(effects.createListConfirm$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
  });
```

The issue I'm having is that the test returns an error @ frame 0 for both test cases and I don't know enough about unit tests or NgRx to tell if there is an issue with the test I've provided or the effect.

Config:

```
  const createListReq: CreateListRequest<BaseListConfig> = { ...createListReq };
  const payload: SubjectSummary = { ...payload };
  const list: CreateListRequest<BaseListConfig> = { ...list };

  let action: Observable<Action>;
  let effects: ListEffects;
  let mockStore: MockStore;
  let listService: jest.Mocked<ListService>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [AngularTestingModule],
        providers: [
          ListEffects,
          HttpClientTestingModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule,
          Store,
          provideMockActions(() => action),
          provideMockStore({
            initialState: {
              loaded: false,
              loading: false,
              listId: null,
              config: null,
              showFilterRow: false,
              features: null,
            },
          }),
          { provide: ApiService, useValue: mockAndSpyOn(ApiService) },
          {
            provide: ListService, useValue: {
              createList: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(cold('-a|',{ id: '123' }))
          }, },
          
        ],
      });
      effects = TestBed.inject(ListEffects);
      mockStore = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
      action = TestBed.inject(Actions);
      listService = TestBed.inject(ListService) as jest.Mocked<ListService>;
    }),
  );
```

Comment: how are you mocking `listService`? can you show the code?

Comment: Am I supposed to have more code than what I've included? Shouldn't the provider create a mock service from the actual service being imported?

Comment: Sorry I missed that you had an inline mock

Comment: 2 things you can change but probably won't fix your issue: 2nd to last line of your effect should use `map` instead of `switchMap` and remove the `of`. Your expected marble probably shouldn't start with a dash. Other than that it looks ok, you could debug the tests to find the error.